# Why textarea's .focus() and .blur() don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea element in my form as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="advertiseForm" name="advertiseForm"   method="post" >
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="textarea" id="textarea">Please enter additional information here...</textarea>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="advertisementlandedvalidationatclient.js"></script>

</body>
```

Then I put .focus and .blur into a javascript file as

```
advertisementlandedvalidationatclient.js

$("#textarea")
  .focus(function() {
        if (txt == null) return;
        if (txt.value == "Please enter additional information here...") txt.value = '';

  })
  .blur(function() {
        if (txt == null) return;
        if (txt.value == '') txt.value = "Please enter additional information here...";

});
```

When I click or remove the mouse from textarea, `"Please enter additional information here..."` doesn't toggle (appear/disappear).

I tried another approach in this [link](http://www.webune.com/forums/20101025cgtc.html)
It works, that approach needs the function `SetMsg` needs to be on top of the `textarea`.
I don't like that approach because I want to separate HTML and Javascript codes into separate files and because of some other elements I need

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="advertisementlandedvalidationatclient.js"></script> below the form.
```

Why it doesn't work in the first .focus/.blur method and what could be the best approach?
Thanks

Comment: And what is `txt` supposed to be in that code ?

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library, as I don't see one in the html sample you gave? Also why not use the placeholder attribute, or are you trying to support older browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placholder attribute for the input elements

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Please enter additional information here..."></textarea>
```

If you really want this to do this with jQuery, you may fix the code as..

```
$("#textarea")
.focus(function() {
    if ($("#textarea").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#textarea").val() == "Please enter additional information here...") $("#textarea").val('');
})
.blur(function() {
    if ($("#textarea").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#textarea").val() == '') $("#textarea").val('Please enter additional information here...');
});
```